# Data visualization for geographical map

Tags: python, data-visualization, geospatial

I am doing a dissertation on data visualization of land prices in Tanzania.

My intendants want me to use a GIS software to map the data on a map and use python code to visualize it.

My question is how can i use python to draw the maps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform data visualisation, you can use the python library called `matplotlib`

To perform the mapping of data on geographical maps using `matplotlib`, [here](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html) are the examples which helps you to get started.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: it helped tremendously

Comment: @Twagic I am glad that it helped.